# undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass in ruby model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have defined a method inside my model class in ruby as below. But when I try using that method I am getting **undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass**. I am not able to figure out where I am going.

bus.rb

```
def seat_avaliable
    (self.seat - self.students.count)
end
```

Comment: i think `self.seat` is nil .Just put the debugger there and check the value .

Comment: @PardeepSaini I checked it with byebug and the value comes out to be 2

Comment: Can't be. If the error really occurs in this line, and Ruby says `seat` is nil, then it is nil, no matter what your debugger pretends. Say bye to byebug and put a `p self.seat` in the line before and a `.tap {|diff| puts diff}` in the line after the offending line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call or chain methods on a nil object. You're trying to subtract something from `nil` which the error has told you.  So you can fix this with:

```
def seat_avaliable
  if seat.is_a?(Integer) && students&.any?
    seat - students.count > 0
  end
end
```

Change your view code to this

```
<% if bus.seat_available %><td>Seat Available</td><% end %>
```

Comment: I tried using the method you suggested but then I am getting the ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `>=' for nil:NilClass): <% if bus.seat_available >=0 %><td>Seat Available</td><% end %>

Comment: Based on your comment, this should work now, see updated answer.